# Call component from another component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CqR6.jpg

This is my Folder structure.

I want to call `Login` Component from `AppHeader` Component. What will be the folder structure during calling.

My try:
Not working.

```
<script>

    import Login from '../components/auth/Login.vue'

    export default
    {

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Try replacing the `../` with `@/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should accomplish it with

```
import Login from '../../auth/Login'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@` prefix to point to root folder of project then you can go anywhere

```
import Login from '@/...';
```